# BIGINT in SPARK SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, bigint

We have configured Spark SQL(1.3.2) to work on top of Hive and we use Beeline to create the tables.

I was trying to create a table with BIGINT datatype.However I see that the table is getting created with INT datatype when I use the below command

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cars (blank bigint)
USING com.databricks.spark.csv
OPTIONS (path "cars.csv", header "false")
```

However when I use the command below I am able to create a table with bigint datatype

```
CREATE TABLE cars(blank bigint)
```

Can you let me know how can I create a tableBIGINT datatype using first method

Is it because of this

"Integral literals are assumed to be INT by default, unless the number exceeds the range of INT in which case it is interpreted as a BIGINT, or if one of the following postfixes is present on the number."

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-IntegralTypes(TINYINT,SMALLINT,INT,BIGINT)